The user is experiencing an error in their Junit program, despite using assert-equals with two integer numbers
I have used the Assert Equals (Expected, Actual) method which takes two integers value and stores its sum in the Actual variable. I am putting my code below.


public class CalcTest 
{
    @Test
    public void test ()
        {
           Calc CT = new Calc ();
           int actual = CT.add(1,2);
           int expected = 3;
           assertEquals(expected, actual);  
        }   
    }


Expected: I want the correct code with the right output.

What do you have for the 'add' method so far?
